# Showing $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2}-\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}\rightarrow\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, radicals

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2}-\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}\rightarrow\frac{1}{3}$$

I tried to say we can erase the $1$ from the equation, as it's a constant. But I don't know how to do the rest without running into this mistake: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2}-n=\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{n^3}{n^3}+\frac{n^2}{n^3}}-\frac{n}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1-1}{0}$$

Comment: Note $n^3+n^2$ is roughly the cube of $n+(1/3)$.

Comment: Try writing $\sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2} = n\sqrt[3]{1+1/n}$ then using the power series for $\sqrt[3]{1+x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use that $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$. Take $a=\sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2}$, $b=\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}$ and then multiply your expression by $(a^2+ab+b^2)/(a^2+ab+b^2)$. Then use the trick you are trying to use.

Comment: You could (and maybe you should) replace *You should* by *You could*. Consider for example the analogous quantity $\sqrt[\pi]{n^\pi+n^{\pi-1}}-\sqrt[\pi]{n^\pi+1}$, then your approach fails while others yield immediately the limit $1/\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \sqrt[3]{n^3 + n^2} - \sqrt[3]{n^3 + 1} \right) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left\{
n \left[
\left(
1 + \frac 1n
\right)^{\frac 13} - \left(
1 + \frac 1{n^3}
\right)^{\frac 13}
\right]
\right\} = \\
\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left[
n \left(
1 + \frac 1{3n} - 1 - \frac 1{3n^3}
\right)
\right] = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(
\frac 13 - \frac 1{3n^2}
\right) = \frac 13$

Comment: How do you justify your second equals sign?

Comment: It's a power series expansion with all terms after second dropped.

Comment: Part of one, perhaps. I think you need some "big O" notation in there, if you're being rigorous.

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(
1 + \frac 1n
\right)^{\frac 13} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(
1 + \frac 1{3n} + O\left(
\frac 1{n^2}
\right)
\right) = \\
\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(
1 + \frac 1{3n}
\right) + \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}
\left[
O \left(
\frac 1{n^2}
\right)
\right] = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(
1 + \frac 1{3n}
\right)$

Answer (score 0):

My answer here
([Evaluation of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (\sqrt{n^2 + n} - \sqrt[3]{n^3 + n^2}) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433527/evaluation-of-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sqrtn2-n-sqrt3n3-n2/1960185#1960185))
shows that
$\sqrt[a]{n^a+n^{a-c}}
=n+\dfrac{1}{an^{c-1}}+O(n^{-(2c-1)})
$.

If $a=3, c=1$,
$\sqrt[3]{n^3+n^{2}}
=n+\dfrac{1}{3}+O(n^{-1})
$.

If $a=3, c=3$,
$\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}
=n+\dfrac{1}{3n^2}+O(n^{-5})
=n+O(n^{-2})
$.

Their difference is,
therefore,
$\frac1{3}+O(n^{-1})
\to \frac13
$.