# The limit of a difference between a cube root and square root

Tags: calculus

I've been trying to evaluate the limit of $$\lim_{x \to \infty}[(x^3+x^2+1)^{1/3}-(x^2+x)^{1/2}]$$ I've tried using the property $$x^6-y^6 =(x-y)(x^5+x^4y+\cdots+xy^4+y^5)$$

where $x = (x^3+x^2+1)^{1/3}$ and $y=(x^2+x)^{1/2}$. But I can't seem to 'clean up' the denominator to get in a position to take the limit. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264180/limit-with-square-and-cube-root-difference-lim-n-to-infty-left-sqrtn2

Comment: $$=\lim_{x\to \infty}[(x^3+x^2+1)^{1/3}-x]-\lim_{x\to \infty}[(x^2+x)^{1/2}-x]$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using your property, you have 
\begin{align}
(x^3+x^2+1)^{1/3}-(x^2+x)^{1/2}&=\frac{(x^3+x^2+1)^2-(x^2+x)^3}{(x^3+x^2+1)^{5/3}+\cdots+(x^2+x)^{5/2}}\\ \ \\
&=\frac{-x^5-2x^4+x^3+2x^2+1}{(x^3+x^2+1)^{5/3}+\cdots+(x^2+x)^{5/2}}\\ \ \\
&=\frac{-1-2/x+1/x^2+2/x^3+1/x^5}{(1+1/x+1/x^3)^{5/3}+\cdots+(1+1/x)^{5/2}}\\ \ \\
&\to-\frac16
\end{align}
(where in the last equality you divide numerator and denominator by $x^5$, and then use the fact that there are six terms in the denominator).

Also here is the way to do this limit that comes naturally to me. From the binomial series, $(1+a)^b\simeq 1+\frac ab$ for small $a$. Then, for small $x$,
\begin{align}
(x^3+x^2+1)^{1/3}-(x^2+x)^{1/2}&=x\,\left[ (1+1/x+1/x^3)^{1/3}-(1+1/x)^{1/2} \right]\\ \ \\
&\simeq x\,\left[1+\frac1{3x}+\frac1{3x^3}-1-\frac1{2x} \right]\ \\ \ \\
&=x\,\left[-\frac{1}{6x}+\frac1{3x^3} \right]=-\frac16+\frac1{3x^2}\\ \ \\
&\to-\frac16.
\end{align}

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: You are very welcome. I have also added another way of doing it.

Answer (score 7):

Replace $x$ by $\frac{1}{t}$ where we think of $t$ as small positive. Our expression becomes
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{(1+t+t^3)^{1/3}-(1+t)^{1/2}}{t}.$$
To find the limit as $t\to 0^+$ use L'Hospital's Rule.
If we don't want to use L'Hospital's Rule, we can rewrite as 
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{\left((1+t+t^3)^{1/3}-1\right)-\left((1+t)^{1/2}-1\right)}{t},$$
and recognize the difference of two derivatives.

Comment: A very elegant approach to the problem. Thank you kind sir!

Comment: You are welcome. The approach you took works nicely also. Another useful way of looking at the problem is through series. It looks a little messier but is more fundamental.

Comment: Another solution: multiply $\frac{(1+t+t^3)^{1/3}-1}{t}$ by $$\frac{(1+t+t^3)^{2/3}+(1+t+t^3)^{1/3}+1}{(1+t+t^3)^{2/3}+(1+t+t^3)^{1/3}+1}$$ and use the formula $$a^k-b^k=(a-b)(a^{k-1}+a^{k-2}b+\cdots+b^{k-1})$$ $k\ge 2$, $k\in\mathbb Z$, $a,b\in\mathbb R$.