# Computing this limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[3]{n^3+5n^2+6}-\sqrt{n^2+3n+4}}$$

At first glance, we see that it's an indeterminate form ($\infty-\infty$). Here are my tries:

I.) I tried to form $a^2-b^2$ in the numerator, where $\cdots$ represents something that $\to 0$:
$$\frac{n^2(\sqrt[3]{1+\cdots}-1)-3n-4}{n(\sqrt[3]{1+\cdots}+\sqrt{1+\cdots})}$$

II.) I tried to form $a^3-b^3$ in the numerator, same as I.):
$$\frac{n^3(1-\sqrt[3]{1+\cdots})+5n^2+6}{n^2(\sqrt{1+\cdots}+\sqrt{1+\cdots}\sqrt{1+\cdots}+1)+3n+4}$$

What method can I apply here?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with Taylor series?

Comment: At first glance, the answer is $\infty$.

Comment: use binomial theorem and binomial approximation,eg$(1+x)^n\approx 1+nx$ where $x<1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Combine the two approaches, $a^2-b^2$ and $a^3-b^3$. But calculate it as the limit of
$$
(\root3\of{n^3+5n^2+6}-n)+(n-\sqrt{n^2+3n+4}),
$$
and do the limits of the above two differences in parens separately.

Comment: Turning this into CW. I used the same trick [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/433544/11619) earlier, and should have remembered that. IMO it is not in the spirit of the site to reuse answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

$$\sqrt[3]{n^3+5n^2+6}-\sqrt{n^2+3n+4} = n\cdot \left(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{6}{n^3}} - \sqrt{1+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{4}{n^2}}\right).$$

L'Hospital rules should help from here on.

Answer (score 0):

Using series:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt[3]{n^3+5n^2+6}-\sqrt{n^2+3n+4} &= n\left( \left(1+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{6}{n^3}\right)^{1/3}  - \left(1+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{4}{n^2}\right)^{1/2} \right) \\
&= n\left( 1+\frac{5}{3n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)  - \left(1+\frac{3}{2n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) \right) \\
&= n\cdot\frac{1}{6n} + o(1) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{1}{6}
\end{align*}

Comment: i think there is some mistakes,we should get nswer as $\frac{1}{6}$ ,right?

Comment: Yes (I had made a mistake at first, but fixed it).