# Find $\lim_{x\to ∞} (\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+3x^{2}}-\sqrt{x^{2}-2x})$ without L'Hopital or Taylor series.

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> $$\large \lim_{x\to ∞} (\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+3x^{2}}-\sqrt{x^{2}-2x})$$

My try is as follows:

$$\large \lim_{x\to ∞} (\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+3x^{2}}-\sqrt{x^{2}-2x})=$$$$ \lim_{x\to 
∞}x\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{3}{x}}-\sqrt{1\ -\frac{2}{x}}\right)$$$$=\lim_{x\to ∞}x\lim_{x\to 
∞}\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{3}{x}}-\sqrt{1\ -\frac{2}{x}}\right)$$
which is $∞×0$ , but clearly this zero is not exactly zero. I was thinking about generalized binomial 
theorem, but seems it will make the limit difficult, so how this kind of limits can be solved without using Taylor series or L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: How does generalised binomial theorem make the limit difficult? You would just get$$x\left(1+\frac1x+o\left(\frac1x\right)-\left(1-\frac1x+o\left(\frac1x\right)\right)\right)=2+o(1)$$hence the limit is $2$.

Comment: thanks, I understand your solution, but is there any elementary way to solve the problem?

Comment: @MartinR Almost [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1429273/505767).

Comment: @Absurd: For a general method, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3585298/21820).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We first note that for any positive integer $n$ and any real $a$,
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}x\left(\sqrt[n]{1+\frac{a}{x}}-1\right)=
\lim_{s\to 1}a\frac{s-1}{s^n-1}=\lim_{s\to 1}\frac{a}{s^{n-1}+s^{n-2}+\dots +s +1}=\frac{a}{n}$$
where $s=\sqrt[n]{1+a/x}$ and therefore $a/x=s^n-1$, and $x=a/(s^n-1)$.

Hence, from your work, we split the limit in two:
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to +\infty} (\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+3x^{2}}-\sqrt{x^{2}-2x})
&=\lim_{x\to +\infty}x\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{3}{x}}-\sqrt{1\ -\frac{2}{x}}\right)
\\&=\lim_{x\to +\infty}x\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{3}{x}}-1\right)-\lim_{x\to \infty}x\left(\sqrt[2]{1 +\frac{-2}{x}}-1\right)\\&=\frac{3}{3}-\frac{-2}{2}=1+1=2.
\end{align}$$

P.S. Note that on the other side,
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} (\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+3x^{2}}-\sqrt{x^{2}-2x})=-\infty$$

Comment: ,awesome, I just think you forgot an $a$ in the third line.

Comment: it's right now,thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using high-school math:$$\lim_{x\to ∞} (\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+3x^{2}}-\sqrt{x^{2}-2x})=\lim_{x\to ∞} \frac{\sqrt[3]{(x^{3}+3x^{2})^2}-x^{2}+2x}{\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+3x^{2}}+\sqrt{x^{2}-2x}}=$$ $$ \lim_{x\to ∞} \frac{(x^{3}+3x^{2})^2-(x^{2}-2x)^3}{(\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+3x^{2}}+\sqrt{x^{2}-2x})(\sqrt[3]{(x^{3}+3x^{2})^4}+\sqrt[3]{(x^{3}+3x^{2})^2}(x^{2}-2x)+(x^2-2x)^2)}=$$ $$\lim_{x\to ∞} \frac{12x^5-3x^4+8x^3}{(\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+3x^{2}}+\sqrt{x^{2}-2x})(\sqrt[3]{(x^{3}+3x^{2})^4}+\sqrt[3]{(x^{3}+3x^{2})^2}(x^{2}-2x)+(x^2-2x)^2)}=$$ $$[\text{leaving the highest power}]=\lim_{x\to ∞} \frac{12x^5}{(x+x)(x^4+x^4+x^4)}=2$$

Answer (score 1):

A quite elementary way is just using the two binomial formulas $a-b=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a+b}$ and $a-b=\frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+ab+b^2}$ as follows:

\begin{eqnarray*}\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+3x^{2}}-\sqrt{x^{2}-2x}
& = & (\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+3x^{2}} - x) + (x -\sqrt{x^{2}-2x})\\
& = & \frac{3x^2}{\sqrt[3]{(x^{3}+3x^{2})^2} + x\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+3x^{2}} + x^2} + \frac{2x}{x+\sqrt{x^{2}-2x}}\\
& = & \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{(1+\frac{3}{x})^2} + \sqrt[3]{1+\frac{3}{x}} + 1} + \frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{x}}} \\
& \stackrel{x\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} & 1+1 = 2
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

By [**binomial approximation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_approximation)

- $\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+3x^{2}}=x\sqrt[3]{1+3/x}\approx x\left(1+\frac1x\right)=x+1$
- $\sqrt{x^{2}-2x}=x\sqrt{1-2/x}\approx x\left(1-\frac1x\right)=x-1$

therefore

$$\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+3x^{2}}-\sqrt{x^{2}-2x}\approx 2$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Set $1/n=h$

$$x^3+3x^2=\dfrac{1+3h}{h^3}, x^2-2x=\dfrac{1-2h}{h^2}$$

$$\large \lim_{x\to\infty} (\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+3x^{2}}-\sqrt{x^{2}-2x})$$
$$=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1+3h}-\sqrt{1-2h}}h$$
$$=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1+3h}-1}h-\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\sqrt{1-2h}-1}h$$

Set $\sqrt[3]{1+3h}-1=p\implies1+3h=(1+p)^3, h=p+p^2+\dfrac{p^3}3$

and $\sqrt{1-2h}-1=q\implies1-2h=(1+q)^2,-h=q+\dfrac{q^2}2$

Answer (score -1):

From OP's work
$$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x \left[ \left( 1+\frac{3}{x} \right)^{1/3}-\left( 1-\frac{2}{x} \right)^{1/2}\right]= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x \left[ \left( 1+\frac{3}{3x} \right)-\left( 1-\frac{2}{2x} \right)\right]= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}x \frac{2}{x}=2. $$