# Cubic roots and difference of cubes in limits $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (\sqrt[3]{n^6-6n^4+1} - n^2)$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

Find the limit:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (\sqrt[3]{n^6-6n^4+1} - n^2)$$

I applied the identity:
$$a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$
by multiplying the numerator and denominator by the complementary part.

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{(\sqrt[3]{n^6-6n^4+1} - n^2)(\sqrt[3]{(n^6-6n^4+1)^2} + n^2\sqrt[3]{n^6-6n^4+1}+ n^4)}{(\sqrt[3]{(n^6-6n^4+1)^2} + n^2\sqrt[3]{n^6-6n^4+1}+ n^4)}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^6-6n^4+1 - n^6}{(\sqrt[3]{(n^6(1-6/n^2+1/n^6))^2} + n^2\sqrt[3]{n^6(1-6/n^2+1/n^6)}+ n^4)}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{-6n^4+1}{(n^4\sqrt[3]{(1-6/n^2+1/n^6)^2} + n^4\sqrt[3]{(1-6/n^2+1/n^6)}+ n^4)}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{-6+1/n^4}{(\sqrt[3]{(1-6/n^2+1/n^6)^2} + \sqrt[3]{(1-6/n^2+1/n^6)}+ 1)}=\frac{-6}{3}=-2$$

Is there any more elegant way to approach the problem?

Comment: You may be interested in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3585298/21820) for a better understanding of how this trick works, when it works, and how to use it rigorously without needing knowledge of more powerful techniques such as asymptotic expansion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With binomial series, it's $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left[ n^2\left(1-\dfrac6{n^2}+\dfrac1{n^6}\right)^{1/3}-n^2\right]$$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left[ n^2\left(1-\dfrac13\dfrac6{n^2}+O\left(\dfrac1{n^4}\right)\right) -n^2\right]$$

$$=-2$$

Answer (score 4):

A possible way is turning it into a derivative using 
$$n=\frac{1}{\sqrt t}$$

and consider $t\to 0^+$.

Hence,

$$\sqrt[3]{n^6-6n^4+1} - n^2 = \frac{\sqrt[3]{1-6t+t^3}-1}{t}$$
$$\stackrel{t\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow}\left.(\sqrt[3]{1-6t+t^3})'\right|_{t=0}=\frac{-6}{3}=-2$$