# How do I determine $\lim_{x\to 1}(\sqrt[3]{x}-1)/(\sqrt{x}-1)$ without L'Hopital's Rule?

Tags: limits

I need to determine the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}-1}$$

We haven't learned L'Hopital's Rule in class so I can't use it and I have tried substitution, factoring, and multiplying by conjugate but nothing seems to work. Is there a way this problem could be solved without the L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: For example with $$y=\sqrt[6] x$$

Comment: See [this explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3585298/intuitive-motivation-for-limit-computations).

Comment: If you find some answer useful, male sure you upvote it and accept it. There is one providing the most elementary method without substitutions.

Answer (score 5):

Many of the limits involved in Calculus classes may be solved without L' Hospital's rule, by using basic algebraic properties/substitution. In your case, using sustitution $y^6=x$, you get that $y\to 1$ as $x\to 1$ and: 
$$\sqrt{x}-1=y^3-1=(y-1)(y^2+y+1) ~~\textrm{and}~~\sqrt[3]{x}-1=y^2-1=(y-1)(y+1).$$
So 
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}-1}=\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{(y-1)(y+1)}{(y-1)(y^2+y+1)}=\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{y+1}{y^2+y+1}=\frac{1+1}{1^2+1+1}=\frac{2}{3}.$$

Answer (score 2):

I would like to point out that $x\to 1^-$ makes sense for $x\geqslant0$ because of the even root, which is why the proposed substitutions work.

Just as @NikolaosSkout has already said, we can turn to difference of cubes, but you don't need any substitution at all :

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}-1}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}-1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x-1}{(\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1}=\frac{2}{3}$

(:

Comment: +1. Some times we can even avoid substitutions.

Comment: Oh, I upvoted your answer, but forgot to comment.