# A math problem I saw, am I applying L'Hospital's rule correctly?

Tags: limits, derivatives

I saw this problem on a math board / insta:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow3}\frac{\sqrt{3x}-3}{\sqrt{2x-4}-\sqrt{2}}$$

My first step would be take a derivative of the numerator and denominator to see if the limit exists or not, since just plugging in gets me 0/0 which is undefined.

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{3x}-3)=\frac{d}{dx}((3x)^{\frac{1}{2}}-3)=\frac{3}{2}(3x)^{-1/2} $$

and

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{2x-4}-\sqrt{2})=\frac{d}{dx}((2x-4)^{\frac{1}{2}}-\sqrt{2})=\frac{1}{2}(2x-4)^{-1/2}(2)=(2x-4)^{-1/2} $$

Which means at $x=3$ I get $\frac{3}{2}(9)^{1/2}= \frac{9}{2}$ in the numerator and $\sqrt{2}$ in the denominator to get me
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow3}\frac{\sqrt{3x}-3}{\sqrt{2x-4}-\sqrt{2}}=\frac{9}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

So I am curious if I did this correctly, or if I am totally misusing L'Hôpital's rule.

ETA: thanks for noting the exponent error. So $\frac{3}{2}(3x)^{-1/2}$ at $x=3$ should be $\frac{3}{2\sqrt{3(3)}}=\frac{1}{2}$  and $(2x-4)^{-1/2}$ at $x=3$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

for $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Comment: Yes, this looks correct.

Comment: You numerator should be $ 1/2$

Comment: You should get $\frac 32(9)^{-\frac 12} = \frac 3{2\cdot 3} = \frac 12$ in the numerator.  And $(2)^{-\frac 12} = \frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ in the denominator.  To get $\frac {\frac 12}{\frac 1{\sqrt 2}} = \frac {\sqrt 2}2=\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: You are not applying the negative exponents correctly when you evaluate at $x=3$.

Comment: thanks I see the mistake in "accounting" -- forgetting the negative sign. D'oh!

Answer (score 3):

As noticed there is a mistake with a negative exponent, as an alternative by rationalization

$$\frac{\sqrt{3x}-3}{\sqrt{2x-4}-\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{3x}-3}{\sqrt{2x-4}-\sqrt{2}}\frac{\sqrt{3x}+3}{\sqrt{3x}+3}\frac{\sqrt{2x-4}+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2x-4}+\sqrt{2}}=$$

$$=\frac{3x-9}{2x-6}\frac{\sqrt{2x-4}+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3x}+3}=\frac{3}{2}\frac{\sqrt{2x-4}+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3x}+3} \to\frac32\frac{2\sqrt 2}{6}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}2$$

Refer also to the related

- [Understand how to evaluate $\lim _{x\to 2}\frac{\sqrt{6-x}-2}{\sqrt{3-x}-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3858398/505767)

Comment: In the second row, I believe the second fraction is upside down. And then that propagates.

Comment: @alex.jordan Yes of course! Thanks I fix that

Comment: And the actual limit is $\sqrt{2}/2$. But the mistake here coincidentally agrees with the mistake in OPs math where they did not use negative exponents correctly.

Comment: @alex.jordan Indeed this was way I didn't noticed that at first! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Uhm, you get $2^{-1/2}$ in the denominator, not $2^{1/2}=\sqrt{2}$.

Let's try in a different way: first
$$
\lim_{x\to3}\frac{\sqrt{3x}-3}{x-3}=
\lim_{x\to3}\frac{3x-9}{x-3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3x}+3}=\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
Also
$$
\lim_{x\to3}\frac{\sqrt{2x-4}-\sqrt{2}}{x-3}=\lim_{x\to3}\frac{2x-4-2}{x-3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x-4}+\sqrt{2}}=\frac{2}{2\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
Hence your limit is
$$
\lim_{x\to3}\frac{\sqrt{3x}-3}{\sqrt{2x-4}-\sqrt{2}}
=\lim_{x\to3}\frac{\sqrt{3x}-3}{x-3}\,\frac{x-3}{\sqrt{2x-4}-\sqrt{2}}
=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
What's going wrong?

The derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt{3x}-3$ is
$$
f'(x)=\frac{3}{2\sqrt{3x}}
$$
and therefore $f'(3)=3/6=1/2$.

The derivative of $g(x)=\sqrt{2x-4}-\sqrt{2}$ is
$$
g'(x)=\frac{2}{2\sqrt{2x-4}}
$$
and $g'(3)=1/\sqrt{2}$.

You seem to confuse $a^{-1/2}$ with $a^{1/2}$.

Comment: I saw the mistakes I made with the negative exponents, but I am not sure the motivation for what you have here- the first step is a bit opaque to me as I wasn't sure why you chose x-3 as the denominator there, though the rationalization via $\sqrt{3x}+3$ makes a bit more sense...

Comment: @Jesse The idea is to try and write $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ as the quotient of $\frac{f(x)}{x-3}$ by $\frac{g(x)}{x-3}$ to see whether this simplifies the derivation, doing just one rationalization in each case. It does, in this particular case, essentially because a single application of l'Hôpital is needed. It reduces the risk of making mistakes.

Comment: OK, so why x-3 tho? The radical 3x seems to make that less obvious to me.

Comment: @Jesse We want an indeterminate form, don't we? Since both $f(x)=\sqrt{3x}-3$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{2x-4}-\sqrt{2}$ have limit zero for $x\to 3$, we get indeterminate forms (actually the ratios in the definition of derivative) when dividing by $x-3$.