# Getting rid of the root $(x-\sqrt[3]{x^3-1})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How should I get rid of the 3rd root $$(x-\sqrt[3]{x^3-1})?$$

I know how to use $(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})=a-b$ but what can I do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Recall that

$$x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$$

Now, let $y=\sqrt[3]{x^3-1}$

Comment: But will this "get rid of the cube root"? Granted, the OP is not very clear about what they want. Your suggestion works fine if they, for example, want to compute the limit of this as $x\to\infty$ (and possibly for other things), but then the question would become a near duplicate of oldies such as [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/236901).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes you are right, I meant to make it easier to calculate the limit

Comment: Ahh, ok. Thanks for the clarification @gbox! The technique is also used [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/264180/) and in an ultimate form [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/30040/).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, of course it doesn't "get rid of the cube root," it merely rearranges things.  However, reading the OP, it states explicitly "I know how to use $(\sqrt a +\sqrt b))(\sqrt a - \sqrt b)=a-b$, but what can I do in this case?"  So, it seemed evident that the OP was seeking a way to factor.  Does that make sense?  -Mark

Comment: Yup. All clear now.